# Filter angularjs selectize options is giving an error

Tags: angularjs, selectize.js

I am trying to use a filter in the options parameter for angular-selectize directive

```
    <selectize placeholder='Pick some things...' options='myOptions2 | filter: {class: "mammal"}' config="myConfig2" ng-model="myModel3" ng-disabled='disable' required='true'></selectize>
```

Here is the plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/VCyqpO5cRll4bRlquOmD?p=preview

In the console I am getting the error.

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

Comment: The filter runs often and might return a new array each time. Maybe `selectize` is watching the `options` by reference, so it sees a new array constantly and ultimately errors out. If you filter the options once yourself, do you get the same error?

Comment: Yes it does watch options by reference, so only solution is to filter on controller once ?

Comment: I usually suggest that in general for performance, but it may solve this issue as well for you.